# References and bibliography with knitr, ESS and AUCTEX

Tags: natbib, emacs, knitr

I'm trying to get references working in a knitr Rnw document using ESS, AUCTex, TeXLive, and natbib.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
@

<<normal-sample, echo=FALSE>>=
x <- rnorm(100)
plot(x)
@

The moon in June is like a big balloon \citep{smith2012}.

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{/path/to/my/references/refs}

\end{document}
```

When I run `ess-swv-knit` then `ess-swv-PDF` with `M-n r` then `M-n P`, I see errors like:

> Package natbib Warning: Citation Smith2014 on page 23 undefined on
>   input line 374

This is what I think is going on.  Running `ess-swv-PDF` simply calls `pdflatex`, but to get the citations right, the correct number of `bibtex` and `pdflatex` commands need to be run.

Is there an way to do this by simply running `M-n r` then `M-n P`?

Comment: I have re-tagged the question, because it is about `natbib` and not `biblatex`. You can find information about Emacs and `biblatex` with Biber at [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154753/35864) maybe some of that is applicable to BIbTeX as well.

Comment: Instead of writing I have this on this part of the document, can you provide a MWE? Will be easier to understand `;-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the variable `ess-swv-pdflatex-commands` to `latexmk`, so that running `ess-swv.el` (`M-n P`) calls `latexmk` instead of `pdflatex` seems to be working, although I haven't tested extensively.

Update: I've been using this for a few days now and `latexmk` is doing the right thing in that it only runs what is necessary to generate the final document.

Answer (score 0):

A solution not tested (I don't use ESS):

Write this in your `init.el` (or other emacs file of course):

```
(defun compile-ESS ()
  "compilation" 
  (ess-swv-PDF)
  (tex-bibtex-file)
  (ess-swv-PDF)
  (ess-swv-PDF)
)
(global-set-key "the shortcut you want to use" 'compile-ESS)
```

Replacing `the shortcut you want to use` by the one you want to use. Try to not use one that is already bind.

Then `M-n r` and `the shortcut you want to use` to do what you wanna perfom.